# django simple ajax request

Tags: jquery, python, django

I am trying to send a ajax request to my views.py but I dont know how to use the path.
My views is located on my server at `/home/pycode/main/main/apps/builder/views.py.`
The page I am sending the request from is located at `/home/dbs/www/python.html`
Do I need to add something to my urls.py?

views.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python26
from django.http import HttpResponse
def main(request):
    return HttpResponse("from python with love")
```

python.html jquery ajax

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#myform").submit(function() {

    var myCheckboxes = new Array();
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
       myCheckboxes.push($(this).val());
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/main',
        data: { myCheckboxes:myCheckboxes },
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access functions in views you refer to them through their entries in `urls.py` never through their location in the filesystem.

Going through the django tutorial (4 pages) will help immensely.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/

in urls.py you map a url to a function using an entry similar to:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^main/$', 'apps.builder.views.main'),
)
```

Then whenever you type '/main/` as a url it maps to your view function.

Comment: Good answer. To the OP: If you include a trailing slash in `/main/`, make sure to add it to the url in the javascript otherwise you might run into problems.

Comment: but does my app need to be located in `/home/dbs/www/` with my site or does it just have to be somewhere in the server?

Comment: @user1442957 your app can be located anywhere.  If you are using dev server your app will be initialized when you make a request to it default port is :8000 so any request `localhost:8000` will enter your app

Answer (score 2):

An Ajax request is just like any other request as far as the server is concerned. So, yes, you need something in urls.py.

Answer (score 0):

And for ajax request, you can use json response:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils import simplejson

class JsonResponse(HttpResponse):
    """ JSON response

    """
    def __init__(self, content, status=None, mimetype=None):
        """
            @param content: string with json, or python dict or tuple
            @param status: Http status
            @param mimetype: response mimetype
        """
        if not isinstance(content, basestring):
            content = simplejson.dumps(content)
        super(JsonResponse, self).__init__(
            content=content, 
            mimetype=mimetype or 'application/json', 
            status=status
        )
        self['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
        self['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
```